# Проверьте, пожалуйста, запятые

Tags: пунктуация

> Спор невозможно было разрешить ни мирным, ни воинственным путём, и
>   города постановили: найти двух петушков-ровесников и в то утро, когда
>   они впервые подадут голос, лучший из всадников должен вскочить на
>   лошадь и сколько он успеет проскакать до момента встречи на дороге,
>   всё, что оставит позади себя, будет считаться виноградниками его
>   родного города.

Это я всё нарисовала; правильно ль?

---

Для любознательных - легенда целиком.

> Что ещё важно в Италии? Конечно, вино! Из тосканских больше всего нам
>   известно кьянти. Кстати, есть весьма поучительная легенда, про то, как
>   Сиена и Флоренция боролись за земли, где и теперь расположены
>   знаменитые виноградники. Спор невозможно было разрешить ни мирным, ни
>   воинственным путём, и города постановили: найти двух
>   петушков-ровесников и в то утро, когда они впервые подадут голос,
>   лучший из всадников должен вскочить на лошадь и сколько он успеет
>   проскакать до момента встречи на дороге, всё, что оставит позади себя,
>   будет считаться виноградниками его родного города. Сиена выбрала себе
>   самого красивого петушка. Его посадили в специально созданную клетку,
>   заботились, кормили, приходили проведать по очереди всем городом –
>   воспринимали как надежду на победу в затеянном состязании. Флорентийцы
>   выбрали мелкую, бодрую, чёрную птицу и особых сантиментов к ней не
>   испытывали – она вместе с прочими домашними пернатыми проводила своё
>   время во дворе в поисках пищи. Но в тот день, когда петух впервые
>   подал голос, город встрепенулся, тотчас вывели лучшего скакуна и
>   лучший всадник помчался по дороге в сторону Сиены. Так почти всё и
>   досталось Флоренции. Изнеженный петух попросту проспал. Его сладкая
>   жизнь не требовала от него никаких обязательств. Зато его
>   флорентийский чёрный собрат до сих пор красуется на лучших бутылках.

Comment: Перед каждым из двух "и" по запятой не дватает, а после "должен" нужно "будет".

Comment: Alex_ander, пожалуйста, приводите ваш вариант текста в ответе, а то очень сложно разобраться  в коротких записях и понять, о каких запятых идет речь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спор невозможно было разрешить ни мирным, ни **военным** путём, и города постановили: найти двух петушков-ровесников, и в то утро, когда они впервые подадут голос, лучший **всадник в каждом городе должен вскочить на лошадь и скакать (мчаться) навстречу сопернику**; все, что **он** оставит позади себя, будет считаться виноградниками его родного города.

Комментарии

1. Ни мирным, ни воинственным(?!) путём.

Как вариант: "ни мирным, ни военным путём".

2. Когда петушки (оба) подадут голос, всадник (один) должен вскочить на лошадь?!

Как вариант: "когда они впервые подадут голос, лучший всадник в каждом из двух городов должен вскочить на лошадь"

3. Сколько успеет, проскакать до момента встречи на дороге?! - Коряво.

Как вариант: "скакать изо всех сил до момента встречи на дороге". Остальное и так понятно.

4. Вскочить и скакать - неблагозвучно

Как вариант: мчаться изо всех сил.

Comment: М_Г, пожалуйста, приводите свой вариант текста (ведь это нетрудно  и недолго), а уже потом комментарии.  Когда текст дан полностью, видны все его достоинства и недостатки.

Comment: @Jasmin Ваше пожелание выполнил.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь мне удобно читать. 1) Воинственный или военный путь. Военный - связанный с войной, воинственный - в духе войны.  Замена оправдана, дух войны выражен, стиль  ближе к художественному. 2) В каждом из двух городов - но из текста ясно, что речь идет о двух городах. 3) до встречи - до момента встречи, лишнее слово. 4) сколько успеет - более конкретно, чем мчаться изо всех сил, к тому же  мчаться - это штамп.  А вскочить - проскакать не слишком заметны в общем тексте, да и нечем их заменить.  А всё остальное очень хорошо.

Comment: Пример у классика: Когда Иван Гора взял знамя, Телегин оставил командный пункт, вскочил на лошадь и поскакал на пойму. [А. Н. Толстой. Хождение по мукам/ Книга третья. Хмурое утро (1941)]

Comment: Только одно мне не по душе: "сколько успеет". Звучит успокаивающе (сколько успеет, столько и будет). Может, сказать "(успеть) проскакать как можно дальше до момента встречи с соперникам"?

Comment: Применяем принцип инфостиля: что и так ясно из текста, не надо подробно описывать  в каждом предложении. А что всадник постарается "проскакать как можно дальше до момента встречи с соперникам", то это не вызывает сомнения.

Comment: Так пусть просто скачет, раз и так ясно: "вскочить на лошадь и скакать (мчаться) навстречу сопернику" - просто и со вкусом! А всё, что он оставит позади себя, будет считаться виноградниками его родного города.

Comment: Нет, нужно именно проскакать, приставка ПРО здесь отмеряет расстояние будущих виноградников.

Answer (score 2):

Спор невозможно было разрешить ни мирным, ни воинственным путём, и города постановили: **(надо)** найти двух петушков-ровесников, (1) и в то утро, когда они впервые подадут голос, лучший из всадников **в каждом городе** должен вскочить на лошадь и, (2)сколько  успеет,(3) проскакать до  встречи **с соперником** на дороге; (4) всё, что **он** оставит позади себя, будет считаться виноградниками его родного города.

**Запятая 1** разделяет простое безличное предложение и блок н основе подчинительной связи.

**Запятые 2 и 3** выделяют придаточное;

**Точка с запятой 4** ставится при открытии новой темы.

Добавлено **"в каждом городе, с соперником"** для ясности ситуации.